# in Ipython notebook / Jupyter, Pandas is not displaying the graph I try to plot

Tags: python, pandas, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to plot some data using pandas in Ipython Notebook, and while it gives me the object, it doesn't actually plot the graph itself. So it looks like this:

```
In [7]:

pledge.Amount.plot()

Out[7]:

<matplotlib.axes.AxesSubplot at 0x9397c6c>
```

The graph should follow after that, but it simply doesn't appear. I have imported matplotlib, so that's not the problem. Is there any other module I need to import?

Comment: I was able to plot things a couple days ago, while following a video,but now I can't seem to plot anything.  and I seem to be doing the same thing as the documentation. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html So I figure something with my system is wrong or a module isn't imported

Comment: @chrisfs there is a newer correct answer. The one you selected a few years ago is now incorrect. Will you consider changing your accepted answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 185, accepted):

Note that --pylab is deprecated and has been removed from newer builds of IPython,  The recommended way to enable inline plotting in the IPython Notebook is now to run:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

See [this post](http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/ipython-dev/2014-March/013411.html) from the ipython-dev mailing list for more details.

Comment: Very good. After using `%matplotlib inline` my attempts to plot resulted in inline visible image, nice. In fact, the import is not  necessary if the plot is method of already existing object like in OP.

Comment: This is the new correct answer.  More info [in this blog post](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/Carreau/posts/blob/master/10-No-PyLab-Thanks.ipynb).

Comment: @Tal Yarkoni I added first line of your answer so that it worked. thanks~~!

Comment: Also applies to pandas in Jupyter notebook.

Comment: For completeness sake, `%matplotlib nbagg` is useful these days to get a more interactive version.

Comment: @FrederickNord It failed to display with nbagg.

Answer (score 50):

Edit:Pylab has been deprecated please see the current accepted answer

Ok, It seems the answer is to start ipython notebook with --pylab=inline. 
so ipython notebook --pylab=inline
This has it do what I saw earlier and what I wanted it to do. 
Sorry about the vague original question.

Comment: Yes, that's what you need. You can also run `%pylab inline` inside a notebook to enable pylab mode.

Comment: note that it does not have to be in inline mode though for pandas to work. I am happily using just `ipython notebook --pylab` with pandas to have the plot in an extra window, if that's what someone wants.

Answer (score 27):

With your `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` just add

```
plt.show()
```

and it will show all stored plots.

Comment: ok that helps.  I thought Ipython would do inline plots automatically. 
The documentation for pandas also doesn't show having to do plt.show()
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html

Answer (score 4):

simple after importing the matplotlib you have execute one magic if you have started the ipython as like this

```
ipython notebook 

%matplotlib inline
```

run this command everything will be shown perfectly

Answer (score 1):

start ipython with `ipython notebook --pylab inline` ,then graph will show inline.

Comment: Yes, that was the first answer on this question, but it also seems to be deprecated now.

Answer (score -2):

```
import matplotlib as plt
%matplotlib as inline
```

Answer (score -5):

All you need to do is to **import** matplotlib.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Comment: `I have imported matplotlib`

Comment: hmmm that's weird.  what do you use? I use iPython Notebook. my code below. data.plot (kind = 'barh', stacked = True)

Comment: This answer is a repeat of the accepted answer above.