# interactive conditional histogram bucket slicing data visualization

Tags: python, pandas, data-visualization, seaborn, bokeh

I have a df that looks like:

```
df.head()
Out[1]:
        A   B   C
city0   40  12  73
city1   65  56  10
city2   77  58  71
city3   89  53  49
city4   33  98  90
```

An example df can be created by the following code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(100,size=(1000000,3)), columns=list('ABC'))

indx = ['city'+str(x) for x in range(0,1000000)]
df.index = indx
```

What I want to do is:

a) determine appropriate histogram bucket lengths for column A and assign each city to a bucket for column A

b) determine appropriate histogram bucket lengths for column B and assign each city to a bucket for column B

Maybe the resulting df looks like (or is there a better built in way in pandas?)

```
    df.head()
    Out[1]:
            A   B   C  Abkt Bbkt
    city0   40  12  73  2  1
    city1   65  56  10  4  3
    city2   77  58  71  4  3
    city3   89  53  49  5  3
    city4   33  98  90  2  5
```

Where Abkt and Bbkt are histogram bucket identifiers:

```
1-20 = 1
21-40 = 2
41-60 = 3
61-80 = 4
81-100 = 5
```

Ultimately, I want to better understand the behavior of each city with respect to columns A, B and C and be able to answer questions like:

a) What does the distribution of Column A (or B) look like - i.e. what buckets are most/least populated.

b) Conditional on a particular slice/bucket of Column A, what does the distribution of Column B look like - i.e. what buckets are most/least populated.

c) Conditional on a particular slice/bucket of Column A and B, what does the behavior of C look like.

Ideally, I want to be able to visualize the data (heat maps, region identifiers etc). I'm a relative pandas/python newbie and don't know what is possible to develop.

If the SO community can kindly provide code examples of how I can do what I want (or a better approach if there are better pandas/numpy/scipy built in methods) I would be grateful.

As well, any pointers to resources that can help me better summarize/slice/dice my data and be able to visualize at intermediate steps as I proceed with my analysis.

**UPDATE:**

I am following some of the suggestions in the comments.

I tried:

1) `df.hist()`

```
ValueError: The first argument of bincount must be non-negative
```

2) `df[['A']].hist(bins=10,range=(0,10))`

```
array([[<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x000000A2350615C0>]], dtype=object)
```

Isn't `#2` suppose to show a plot? instead of producing an object that is not rendered? I am using `jupyter notebook`.

Is there something I need to turn-on / enable in `Jupyter Notebook` to render the histogram objects?

**UPDATE2:**

I solved the rendering problem by: [in Ipython notebook, Pandas is not displying the graph I try to plot.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10511024/in-ipython-notebook-pandas-is-not-displying-the-graph-i-try-to-plot)

**UPDATE3:**

As per suggestions from the comments, I started looking through [pandas visualization](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html), [bokeh](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/) and [seaborn](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/). However, I'm not sure how I can create linkages between plots.

Lets say I have 10 variables. I want to explore them but since 10 is a large number to explore at once, lets say I want to explore 5 at any given time (r,s,t,u,v).

If I want an interactive hexbin with marginal distributions plot to examine the relationship between r & s, how do I also see the distribution of t, u and v given interactive region selections/slices of r&s (polygons).

I found hexbin with marginal distribution plot here [hexbin plot](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/examples/hexbin_marginals.html):

**But:**

1) How to make this interactive (allow selections of polygons)

2) How to link region selections of r & s to other plots, for example 3 histogram plots of t,u, and v (or any other type of plot).

This way, I can navigate through the data more rigorously and explore the relationships in depth.

Comment: A quick and easy way to find out what the distributions of your columns look like is to use `df.hist()`. As for "what is possible to develop"? Well, just about anything but it will depend greatly on your dataset. One place to start might be the [pandas visualization page](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html)

Comment: I keep getting ValueError: The first argument of bincount must be non-negative for df.hist(), df[['A']].hist(bins=10,range=(0,20)), etc.

Comment: I solved the rendering issue via: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10511024/in-ipython-notebook-pandas-is-not-displying-the-graph-i-try-to-plot

Comment: For visualizations (notably heatmaps) I recommend [seaborn](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/index.html).

Comment: For your issue with #1 it could be that you have `inf`s in your dataframe a la https://github.com/JosPolfliet/pandas-profiling/issues/6

Comment: I've been looking through the http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html and http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/ecosystem.html#ecosystem-visualization, and I'm not sure how I can create *linkages* between plots. Lets say I have 5 variables (r,s,t,u,v). If I want an interactive hexbin with marginal distributions plot to examine the relationship between r&s, how do I also see the distribution of t, u and v given interactive region selections/slices of r&s (polygons).

Comment: I found hexbin with marginal distribution plot here: http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/examples/hexbin_marginals.html. But how to make this interactive (allow selections of polygons). And how do I link selections to say 3 histogram plots of t,u, and v (or any other type of plot).

Comment: You might try looking at some of the examples here: http://matplotlib.org/examples/index.html. In particular, look at the event handling examples.

Comment: How can a freelancer contact you?

Comment: Regarding interactive plots with Jupyter Notebooks, take a look at plotly, in particular these examples show you how to make dropdown menus to control certain variables, and could easily be extended to histograms: https://plot.ly/python/dropdowns/  Also, check out the Freedman-Diaconis rule for creating the optimal # of bins in a histogram: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/798/calculating-optimal-number-of-bins-in-a-histogram

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a new solution using [`bokeh`](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/charts.html) and [`HoloViews`](http://holoviews.org/#installation). It should respond a little more to the interactive part.

I try to remember that *simple is beautiful* when it comes to dataviz.

I used [`faker`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fake-factory) library in order to generate random city names to make the following graphs more realistic.

I will let all my codes here even if the most important part is the choice of the libraries.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from faker import Faker

def generate_random_dataset(city_number, 
                        list_identifier,
                        labels,
                        bins,
                        city_location='en_US'):

    fake = Faker(locale=city_location)

    df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.uniform(0, 100, len(list_identifier)]), 
                      index=[fake.city() for _ in range(city_number)], 
                      columns=list_identifier)

    for name in list_identifier:
        df[name + 'bkt'] =  pd.Series(pd.cut(df[name], bins, labels=labels))

    return df

list_identifier=list('ABC')
labels = ['Low', 'Medium', 'Average', 'Good', 'Great']
bins = np.array([-1, 20, 40, 60, 80, 101])

df = generate_random_dataset(30, list_identifier, labels, bins)

df.head()
```

will output:
[image: df]

Sometimes, when your dataset is small, exposing a simple chart with colors could be enough.

```
from bokeh.charts import Bar, output_file, show
from bokeh.layouts import column

bar = []
for name in list_identifier:
    bar.append(Bar(df, label='index', values=name, stack=name+'bkt',
               title="percentage of " + name, legend='top_left', plot_width=1024))

output_file('cities.html')

show(column(bar))
```

Will create a new html page (cities) containing the graphs. Note that all the graphs generated with `bokeh` are interactive.

[image: graphA]

[image: graphB]

`bokeh` can't initially plot hexbin. However, `HoloViews` can. Thus, it allows to draw interactive plots whitin `ipython notebook`.

The syntax is quite straightforward, you just need a Matrix with two columns and call the hist method:

```
import holoviews as hv
hv.notebook_extension('bokeh')

df = generate_random_dataset(1000, list_identifier, list(range(5)), 5)

points = hv.Points(np.column_stack((df.A, df.B)))
points.hist(num_bins=5, dimension=['x', 'y'])
```

[image: repartition of A and B]

To compare with @piRSquared solution, I stole a bit of code (thank you btw :) to show the data with some correlation:

```
mean, cov = [0, 1], [(1, .5), (.5, 1)]
data = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean, cov, 100000)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["A", "B"])

df.index = df.index.to_series().astype(str).radd('city')

df_ = pd.cut(df[['A', 'B']].stack(), 30, labels=list(range(30))).unstack()
df_.columns = df_.columns.to_series() + 'bkt'

points = hv.Points(np.column_stack((df_.Abkt, df_.Bbkt)))
points.hist(num_bins=5, dimension=['x', 'y'])
```

[image: mean covariance]

Please consider visit `HoloViews` [tutorial](http://holoviews.org/Tutorials/Bokeh_Backend.html).

Comment: This is great. Thank you. I'm wondering if its possible to create a hexbin plot that looks simillar to the one from seaborn. This plot is beautiful. My preference for the interactive mechanism would allow the user to select a) slices from the marginal distributions and/or b) hexagons from the plot. I would like to link the selections to another plot(s) that show further info. Is this possible? http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/examples/hexbin_marginals.html.

Comment: I don't know if it's possible since I'm a newbie in Holoview. I will have a look this weekend and edit this answer if I find the solution!

Comment: It is not possible yet to draw hexbin plot like `seaborn` yet using python, but it's under discussion. https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/4342 However, the feature is avaible in `R` with `rbokeh` https://www.r-bloggers.com/plotting-lots-of-data-with-rbokeh/

Answer (score 6):

In order to get the interaction effect you're looking for, you must bin all the columns you care about, together.

The cleanest way I can think of doing this is to `stack` into a single `series` then use `pd.cut`

Considering your sample `df`

[image]

```
df_ = pd.cut(df[['A', 'B']].stack(), 5, labels=list(range(5))).unstack()
df_.columns = df_.columns.to_series() + 'bkt'
pd.concat([df, df_], axis=1)
```

[image]

---

Let's build a better example and look at a visualization using `seaborn`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=(np.random.randn(10000) * 100 + 20).astype(int),
                       B=(np.random.randn(10000) * 100 - 20).astype(int)))

import seaborn as sns

df.index = df.index.to_series().astype(str).radd('city')

df_ = pd.cut(df[['A', 'B']].stack(), 30, labels=list(range(30))).unstack()
df_.columns = df_.columns.to_series() + 'bkt'

sns.jointplot(x=df_.Abkt, y=df_.Bbkt, kind="scatter", color="k")
```

[image]

---

Or how about some data with some correlation

```
mean, cov = [0, 1], [(1, .5), (.5, 1)]
data = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean, cov, 100000)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["A", "B"])

df.index = df.index.to_series().astype(str).radd('city')

df_ = pd.cut(df[['A', 'B']].stack(), 30, labels=list(range(30))).unstack()
df_.columns = df_.columns.to_series() + 'bkt'

sns.jointplot(x=df_.Abkt, y=df_.Bbkt, kind="scatter", color="k")
```

[image]

---

#### Interactive `bokeh`

Without getting too complicated

```
from bokeh.io import show, output_notebook, output_file

from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.layouts import row, column
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Select, CustomJS

output_notebook()

# generate random data
flips = np.random.choice((1, -1), (5, 5))
flips = np.tril(flips, -1) + np.triu(flips, 1) + np.eye(flips.shape[0])

half = np.ones((5, 5)) / 2
cov = (half + np.diag(np.diag(half))) * flips
mean = np.zeros(5)

data = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean, cov, 10000)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=list('ABCDE'))

df.index = df.index.to_series().astype(str).radd('city')

# Stack and cut to get dependent relationships
b = 20
df_ = pd.cut(df.stack(), b, labels=list(range(b))).unstack()

# assign default columns x and y.  These will be the columns I set bokeh to read
df_[['x', 'y']] = df_.loc[:, ['A', 'B']]

source = ColumnDataSource(data=df_)

tools = 'box_select,pan,box_zoom,wheel_zoom,reset,resize,save'

p = figure(plot_width=600, plot_height=300)
p.circle('x', 'y', source=source, fill_color='olive', line_color='black', alpha=.5)

def gcb(like, n):
    code = """
    var data = source.get('data');
    var f = cb_obj.get('value');
    data['{0}{1}'] = data[f];
    source.trigger('change');
    """
    return CustomJS(args=dict(source=source), code=code.format(like, n))

xcb = CustomJS(
    args=dict(source=source),
    code="""
    var data = source.get('data');
    var colm = cb_obj.get('value');
    data['x'] = data[colm];
    source.trigger('change');
    """
)

ycb = CustomJS(
    args=dict(source=source),
    code="""
    var data = source.get('data');
    var colm = cb_obj.get('value');
    data['y'] = data[colm];
    source.trigger('change');
    """
)

options = list('ABCDE')
x_select = Select(options=options, callback=xcb, value='A')
y_select = Select(options=options, callback=ycb, value='B')


show(column(p, row(x_select, y_select)))
```

[image]

Comment: `stack` and `unstack` is very nice solution ;)

Comment: Nice edit :) Have you took a look at `HoloView` as I described in my solution? it could be useful to have an interactive hexbin since `bokeh` doesn't allow it (yet?). I will try this weekend if you don't have any intention to try (I'm very new to dataviz and I'm eager to try new things). Also, if you have any tutorial or exercices for noobz it would be kind of you to share!

Comment: @MaxChrétien I haven't heard of `HoloView`.  I will take a look.

Comment: Both your answers are great. I thank you kindly. I'm wondering however, how can we ensure that the folks @ Bokeh are aware of this post and desire for interactive hexbin plots. As well, Do the folks @ seaborn have plans to make their plots interactive? The seaborn hexbin plot is beautiful. http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/examples/hexbin_marginals.html. My preference for the interactive mechanism would allow the user to select a) slices from the marginal distributions and/or b) hexagons from the plot. I would like to link the selections to another plot(s) that show further info.

Answer (score 3):

As a newbie with insufficient rep, I can't comment, so I'm putting this here as an "answer," though it shouldn't be treated as one; these are just some incomplete suggestions in the same vein as the comments.

Along with the others, I like `seaborn` though I'm not sure those plots are interactive in the way you are seeking. While I haven't used `bokeh`, my understanding is that it provides more in the way of interactivity, but regardless of the package, as you move beyond 3 and 4 variables, you can only cram so much into one (family of) charts.

As for in your table directly, the aforementioned `df.hist()` (by [lanery](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5285918/lanery)) is a good start. Once you have those bins, you can then play with the [immensely powerful](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) `df.groupby()` function. I've been using pandas for two years now, and that function STILL blows my mind. While not interactive, it will definitely help you slice and dice your data as you see fit.