# error installing graphtool python

Tags: python, installation, graph-tool

I ma trying to isntall graphtool on centos but I receive an error.

This is what I have tried:

```
(python_2.7_numerical) [lpuggini@machinelearn-1 ~]$ pip install git+https://github.com/count0/graph-tool
Collecting git+https://github.com/count0/graph-tool
  Cloning https://github.com/count0/graph-tool to /tmp/pip-dU9eDe-build
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/pip-dU9eDe-build/setup.py'

    ----------------------------------------
```

and

```
(python_2.7_numerical) [lpuggini@machinelearn-1 ~]$ pip install graphtool
Collecting graphtool
  Using cached graphtool-0.5.2.tar.gz
Collecting CherryPy<=3.1 (from graphtool)
  Using cached CherryPy-3.1.0.tar.gz
Collecting matplotlib<=0.90.1 (from graphtool)
  Using cached matplotlib-0.86.2.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    installing data to ./matplotlib/mpl-data
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-16Qbh5/matplotlib/setup.py", line 201, in <module>
        build_transforms(ext_modules, packages, NUMERIX)
      File "setupext.py", line 760, in build_transforms
        add_numpy_flags(module)
      File "setupext.py", line 119, in add_numpy_flags
        module.include_dirs.append(numpy.get_numpy_include())
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'get_numpy_include'
```

I have also tried to  install it manually but it is too complicate due to the large number of dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Since graph-tool uses C under the hood the installation is a little trickier.

Check out the install instructions here https://git.skewed.de/count0/graph-tool/-/wikis/installation-instructions

Answer (score -1):

Which graphtool are you using? if you're using matplotlib
%matplotlib inline

This usually works for me when i'm developing in Azureml

[in Ipython notebook, Pandas is not displying the graph I try to plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10511024/in-ipython-notebook-pandas-is-not-displying-the-graph-i-try-to-plot)